# How to get a value from a delegate and reload a view

Tags: iphone, delegates, popover

I'm developing an iPad app, and it's the first time I put the popover view to good use. I'm using the popover view as a menu with categories, and only have 1 screen with video's. When the user selects a category, the 'FeaturedViewController' has to reload the view with the new playlistId.

When a user selects a category, it's easy to do:  `double playlistId = [[playlists.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] playlistId];`

But how do I get that playlistId in my FeaturedViewController and reload the view?

Comment: have you declare your playlist variable in delegate file ?

Comment: Yes, and I've synthesized it and everything; but dont even get the ID back in NSLog.

Comment: give some more code. how you are trying to get an id ?

Comment: `double playlistId = [[playlists.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] playlistId];` outputs the correct ID, but I just need to pass it on to FeaturedViewController.m and reload the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// load new playlist
BCPlaylist *playlist = (BCPlaylist *) [playlists.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:playlist.playlistId];
NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
FeaturedViewController *nextView = [[FeaturedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
nextView.PLID = key;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
[nextView release];
}
```

The Key NSlogs correctly, but i dont get a response from nextView.PLID in the FeaturedViewController at all.

Comment: Oh by the way, self presentModalViewController doesn't do the job either. That just paints over the main view of course.

Answer (score 0):

in your FeaturedViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     //create reference of your delegate
    YourAppDelegate rootApp = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

     double playlistId = [[[[rootApp playlists] items] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] playlistId ];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**EDITED**

Or you can define a property in FeaturedViewController and assign value in this VC like :

```
FeaturedViewController  nextView = [[FeaturedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeaturedViewController" bundle:nil];
 //below lineset the value of property and you can pass value to nextView
    nextView.playlistId = [[playlists.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] playlistId]; ;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

hope it gives you idea to access variable of delegate

Comment: When I try to NSLog the readwrite double of playlistId, the output is null. I think it does not get pushed to FeaturedViewController and reloaded. What did you mean by object btw? A double isnt an object?

Comment: i was talking about nextView. It's an object of FeaturedViewController. and double is not an object its native data type

Comment: Oh right then I understood you. However I think you misinterpreted the layout when you do pushViewController. I have a single tabbar with 1 item (tabbar is hidden, future purposes). The menu is a popover and the main view is always FeaturedViewController.